# jQuery Using .on() as a replacement for .live()

Tags: jquery

I'm a little confused regarding the .on() method. Let me try and explain:

I need to use .on() in the format of: `$(document).on('click', 'selector', function (e) {});` instead of `$('selector').on('click', function(e) {});` so that it applies to existing elements as well as dynamically loaded ones too.

I've created a simplified example of my issue here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj = $('.testing');

    // Doesn't work
    $(document).on('click', obj, function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).text());
    });

    // Works, but won't work for new elements
    obj.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

When I have the selector already set in a variable with a jQuery instance already wrapped around it `var obj = $('.testing')` it is in the correct format for the 2nd example, but not for the 1st one due to it already being wrapped as a jQuery instance. Going from `'.selector'` to `$('.selector')` is easy, but is there a way to go from `$('.selector')` to `'.selector'`?

My Question is, is there any way to un-wrap the jQuery instance so that I can parse the just the selector rather than it already being wrapped via jQuery?

I've created a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/MzwK8/

Any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit** Sorry, I should have said that in my example I've simplified it a lot, but the selector is already being parsed to a plugin as a jQuery instance like `$('.selector').plugin()`. I should have mentioned that I don't have the capacity to change the `var obj = $('.testing');` line

Comment: Why do even have `var obj = $('.testing');` in the first place? Why not use the selector directly? There was a `selector` property, but it was removed in jQuery 1.9: http://api.jquery.com/selector/.

Comment: What you're trying to do simply doesn't make sense.  A selector is not the same as a list of objects that once were collected to match that selector.  They are different things entirely.  The 2nd argument to `.on()` is a selector string, plain and simple and that's what you MUST pass it.

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry, I should have explained that. It's because I'm using the selector which is used via a plugin, so $('.selector').plugin(); and then using var obj = this in the plugin itself

Comment: @FelixKling - It is just an example. I think it's a good general question.

Comment: Oh, then the link  I posted might "help": *"Plugins that need to use a selector string within their plugin can require it as a parameter of the method. For example, a "foo" plugin could be written as `$.fn.foo = function( selector, options ) { /* plugin code goes here */ };`, and the person using the plugin would write `$( "div.bar" ).foo( "div.bar", {dog: "bark"} );` with the `"div.bar"` selector repeated as the first argument of `.foo()`."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think getting the selector string is the wrong approach to the overall problem, and here is why:

I understand that you want `$('.foo').plugin()` to work with both, *existing* and *future* `.foo` elements, correct?

However, what happens if there are no existing `.foo` elements? The plugin function would not even be executed and so the event delegation wouldn't be set up. That means the plugin would only work for future `.foo` elements *if and only if* there already existing ones. That's a rather confusing behavior from a user perspective.

I think, in your use case it makes more sense to create a static plugin, which just accepts a selector string:

```
$.plugin = function(selector) { ... };

$.plugin('div.bar');
```

---

Many answers mention `obj.selector`, however [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/selector/) marks this property as deprecated and removed. Their suggestion is:

> Plugins that need to use a selector string within their plugin can require it as a parameter of the method. For example, a "foo" plugin could be written as
>
> ```
> $.fn.foo = function( selector, options ) { /* plugin code goes here */ };
> ```
>
> and the person using the plugin would write
>
> ```
> $( "div.bar" ).foo( "div.bar", {dog: "bark"} );
> ```
>
> with the `"div.bar"` selector repeated as the first argument of `.foo()`."

So that's what you should do in your plugin: Require the selector as argument to the plugin method.

Comment: I see what you and the documentation is saying now, but I just feel it's a little bit redundant having to specify the selector twice when calling it.

Comment: Ah of course, didn't even consider that with no elements the initial call would never be triggered. I think a static plugin looks to be the way to go to keep it simple. I really appreciate your help with this issue

Comment: You're welcome! Sometimes it's easy to get lost in the details and miss the big picture (I missed it too ;) ).

Comment: Just wanted to say that the plugin would still be called even if no elements match it using the method of `$('selector').plugin();` probably explains why I didn't consider it as an potential issue. More info here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1955

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter should be a selector, not a jQuery object:

```
$(document).on('click', '.testing', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

If possible you should bind the event on the existing element closest to the elements that you will be adding. That way it doesn't have to test the selector for every click that happens in the page.

Comment: Yes, I'm fully aware of that. Perhaps I've simplified my example too much, but I'm getting the selector via $('.selector').plugin();

Comment: @JamieBicknell: If the jQuery object was created using a selector, you can just use `obj.selector` to get it (although that property is deprecated). If the jQuery object wasn't created that way, you can't use it to bind a delegate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retreive the original selector you can do this:

```
var obj = $('.testing');
console.log( obj.selector); // will log .testing
```

Comment: `.selector` was removed in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: That's it, thank you. I felt as though I knew what I needed but couldn't find it because I didn't know the name of it. This will be my accepted answer when I can accept it

Comment: `.selector` fixed the issue, and I'm running 1.10.2?

Comment: Even when `.selector` existed, it did not always work because there are lots of ways to create jQuery objects, not all of which have their origin with a single selector.  If you want to remember the selector, you should save it yourself so you know what you're getting.

Comment: @JamieBicknell: See the link in my first comment to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This will make your first function work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var obj = $('.testing')[0].className;

        $(document).on('click', "."+obj, function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert($(this).text());
        });
});
```

Comment: Whilst this may work with classes, it wouldn't work if the selector was using HTML elements only or IDs.

Comment: True, but I thought that was what you were asking. This code can be easily adapted to work with IDs, off course.

Comment: I do appreciate your input, but I think compared with other solutions here this would be a little hacky but I thank you for providing this as an option.